# AWS Copilot NLB port:443/tls

Tags: aws-copilot, aws-copilot-cli

I've created a hello world listening to the port 80 and deployed with AWS Copilot using a NLB. It works... Now, I'd like to deployed as Https . So I use the port 443/tls. When deploying it doesn't give any error but simply it doesnt work. The browser would hang for ever if I try to open the URL that copilota tell me to open. Any ideas ?

Tried different ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nlb:
  port: 443/tls
  target_port: 80
```